# MySQL Query for selecting multiple count Column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this-

[image: Table]

I want to run a query so that I can have a output like it-

[image]

I don't have a clear idea how to do it.
So, what I have done is-

```
SELECT
        Count(* where status="Active") as count_active
        Count(* where status="Inctive") as count_inactive
        Count(* where status="Biase") as count_biase
    FROM `subscribers`
```

And getting error, can anyone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can achieve this with a `Case` expression.

**Query**

```
select 
count(case when status = 'Active' then 1 else null end) as Active_Count,
count(case when status = 'Inactive' then 1 else null end) as Inctive_Count,
count(case when status = 'Biase' then 1 else null end) as Biase_Count
from tbl_name;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/faeb48/2)

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to put it in a single register:

```
SELECT 
(SELECT count(id) FROM new_table where status = 'Active') as Active_Count,
(SELECT count(id) FROM new_table where status = 'Inactive') as Inctive_Count,
(SELECT count(id) FROM new_table where status = 'Biase') as Biase_Count;
```